# I am splitting CSV columns into separate lists- why am I getting 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split''?

Tags: python, list, csv, attributeerror

I have a CSV file and am wanting to split each column into separate lists. I know the `.split()` function doesn't work in a list of strings. I have tried using multiple different codes from similar questions on here to fix the error and made a loop to access each line, but I still getting the error
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. What do I need to fix to be able to separate my columns into their own lists?

My code:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader= csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        Type = line.split(",")
        x = Type[1]
        y = Type[2]
        print(x,y)
```

EDIT: I am able to get lists of the rows, but I need separate lists of the columns. To show, this is a small chunk of my file:

```
Age,WorkClass,Final Weight
39,State-gov,77516
31,Private,45781
42,Private,159449
30,Private,188146
30,Private,59496
44,Private,343591
44,Private,198282
32,Self-emp-inc,317660
17,?,304873
28,Private,377869
```

I need separate lists of each variable, so something like:

```
Age= [39, 41, 42, 30, 44, 44, 32, 17, 28]
WorkClass= ['State-gov', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Self-emp-inc', '?', 'Private']
FinalWeight= [77516, 45781, 159449, 188146, 59496, 343591, 304873, 377869]
```

I need to be able to easily access the variables separately which is why I am putting them into their own lists.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error code because you're trying to apply a method (*str.split*) on a list.  I think this happens to all of us at one point or another - the root cause here is really about understanding what the function (csv.reader) is returning.

csv.reader returns a reader object which, according to the documentation, is an iterator that, for each iteration, returns a row of the CSV file (which can span multiple input lines).  If you want to take a peek at what that row looks like, you can manually iterate on this reader object by using next on it:

next(csv_reader)

```
> ['1', '2', '3']  # A row of data, pre split by your designated delimiter.
```

Since csv.reader parses each row based on the delimiter you provided, you don't need to call split on the line - split has already been called on the line so it's already a list.

It's worth mentioning that you've chosen 'type' as your variable name (even with a capital T) - most of us would strongly advise against that. In fact, in this code, you might not even need that Type declaration.

The code snippet your looking for should like this:

```
with open('avocado.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        x = line[1]
        y = line[2]
        print(x, y)
```

My best friend is the help built-in.  If I ever get stuck on input/output, I use help() on the object and it's function in question.

```
help(csv_reader)
help(csv.reader)

Help on built-in function reader in module _csv:

reader(...)
    csv_reader = reader(iterable [, dialect='excel']
                            [optional keyword args])
        for row in csv_reader:
            process(row)
    
    The "iterable" argument can be any object that returns a line
    of input for each iteration, such as a file object or a list.  The
    optional "dialect" parameter is discussed below.  The function
    also accepts optional keyword arguments which override settings
    provided by the dialect.
    
    The returned object is an iterator.  Each iteration returns a row
    of the CSV file (which can span multiple input lines).
```

*** UPDATE ***

If you're trying to transpose CSV data from row to columnar orientation you'll have some options.  I prefer the following method which is iterative and based on position:

```
with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    column_names = next(csv_reader) # Get the headers, keep them as a list.
    # This will meet your primary requirement as output when populated.
    column_data = [[] for x in range(len(column_names))] # Create a list of empty lists.  
    for line in csv_reader:
        for pos, data in enumerate(line): # use enumerate to get an positional index
            column_data[pos].append(data) # append the data point the appropriate list based on position.  

# Unnecessary but useful:  use dict comprehension to 
# create a dictionary for ease of access
transposed = {name: values for name, values in zip(column_names, column_data)} 

# Access any column with dict access
print(transposed['Age']) # ['39', '31', '42', '30', '30', '44', '44', '32', '17', '28']
print(transposed['WorkClass']) # ['State-gov', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Self-emp-inc', '?', 'Private']
print(transposed['Final Weight']) # ['77516', '45781', '159449', '188146', '59496', '343591', '198282', '317660', '304873', '377869']
```

Other methods that work would be include the usage of csv.DictReader and acccessing values by key.  There are many ways to skin this cat - but the the afformentioned example is probably how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` splits the columns for you, that's why `line` is already a `list` and has no `split` method.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv',newline='') as csv_file: # newline='' required per docs
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)         # delimiter=',' is default
    for age,wc,fw in csv_reader:              # returns list of columns for each line
        print(age,wc,fw)
```

If you need column-oriented lists instead of row-oriented, read all the lines at once.  The line lists can be transposed to column lists with `zip`, which takes iterables and returns a list of first items, then next items, etc.  The `*` syntax passes a list of items as separate parameters as required by `zip`:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv',newline='') as csv_file:
    r = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(r) # skip headers
    rows = list(r)                # list of row lists
    age,wc,fw = zip(*rows)        # tuple of column lists (output of zip is tuples)
    age = [int(x) for x in age]   # convert age column to integers
    wc = list(wc)                 # convert work class to list if needed
    fw = [int(x) for x in fw]     # convert final weight column to integers
    print(age,wc,fw,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[39, 31, 42, 30, 30, 44, 44, 32, 17, 28]
['State-gov', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Self-emp-inc', '?', 'Private']
[77516, 45781, 159449, 188146, 59496, 343591, 198282, 317660, 304873, 377869]
```